# How to make diff prefer modification vs add/delete?

Tags: diff

When I run `diff a b`, it prints many lines removed and many added.

However, many of these lines are actually the same line, but modified. In this case, it's a CSV with an extra field added at the end.

I think diff's algorithm probably tries to compare the lines, and if the % of matching characters is too low, considers them add/remove rather than modify. But in my case this threshold is too sensitive. Is there a way to reduce it?

Alternate diff programs are okay as well.

Comment: Please, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: First: **what** diff are you talking about? Have a look at the description of the tag [tag:diff]. If you are taking about the UNIX utility, you might get better answers at [unix.se].